# Can't verify signatuire in 2nd program using nodejs crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, digital-signature

I have two node-js programs. I want to sign a number data in the first program (node1.js) and verify that the in the second program (node2.js). But it is not happening. I think it may be because the way I'm sending the argument in write() is not correct. Please help. Thank You

**node1.js**

```
function between(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(
        Math.random() * (max - min) + min
    )
}

var no = between(10, 100);

var crypto = require('crypto');

const node1PrivateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMH4CAQAwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAMEZzBlAgEBBB4BfZ9QrDb9rRZB+sz5rkcK8VhUAJyJRj6KlOlEVYChQAM+AARylnQB587rYJlx/BvMIdtmLoMfzrCcYzrSMWxSX0tseCpunG03pBnE1mDuIo8lCnxm0kZYC4PUrr9r4f8=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

//var node1PublicKey = new Buffer("MFIwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAMDPgAEGrIPBS4+TSe1rKuuIcGItuYjAgVmIaILaa0MTIcTb7sth05hYtWKwfJA48ZTFQi5iBCH1RqCZyq+nZmB", "hex");
//keypair is correct and generated using other program

const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
sign.write('no');
sign.end();
const signature = sign.sign(node1PrivateKey, 'hex');

module.exports = {
    node1_no: no,
    node1_signature: signature
}
```

**node2.js**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
   
const node1PublicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFIwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAMDPgAEGrIPBS4+TSe1rKuuIcGItuYjAgVmIaILaa0MTIcTb7sth05hYtWKwfJA48ZTFQi5iBCH1RqCZyq+nZmB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    
var node1 = require('./node1.js');
console.log(node1.node1_no);
console.log(node1.node1_signature);

const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
verify.write('node1.node1_no');
verify.end();
console.log(verify.verify(node1PublicKey, node1.node1_signature, 'hex'));
```

*It returns FALSE.
The expected result is TRUE. when I use same variable name ('no') it returns TRUE.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. The problem was `write()` function accepts only string. But I were sending integer value.
Now, I converted integer to string ans pass the value to `write()` function and it worked.

node1.js

```
function between(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(
        Math.random() * (max - min) + min
    )
}
var no = between(10, 100);
var no_str = veh.toString();

var crypto = require('crypto');
const node1PrivateKey = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMH4CAQAwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAMEZzBlAgEBBB4BfZ9QrDb9rRZB+sz5rkcK8VhUAJyJRj6KlOlEVYChQAM+AARylnQB587rYJlx/BvMIdtmLoMfzrCcYzrSMWxSX0tseCpunG03pBnE1mDuIo8lCnxm0kZYC4PUrr9r4f8=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----";
//var node1PublicKey = new Buffer("MFIwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAMDPgAEGrIPBS4+TSe1rKuuIcGItuYjAgVmIaILaa0MTIcTb7sth05hYtWKwfJA48ZTFQi5iBCH1RqCZyq+nZmB", "hex");

const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
sign.write('no_str');
sign.end();
const signature = sign.sign(node1PrivateKey, 'hex');

module.exports = {
    node1_no: no,
    node1_signature: signature
}
```

second.js

```
var crypto = require('crypto');    
const node1PublicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFIwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAMDPgAEGrIPBS4+TSe1rKuuIcGItuYjAgVmIaILaa0MTIcTb7sth05hYtWKwfJA48ZTFQi5iBCH1RqCZyq+nZmB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
var node1 = require('./node1.js');
var no_string = node1.node1_veh
const verify = crypto.createVerify('SHA256');
verify.write('no_string');
verify.end();
console.log(verify.verify(node1PublicKey, node1.node1_signature, 'hex'));
```